# Explain why the IVP has a unique solution of the form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Explain why the IVP : $ x'(t)=\begin{bmatrix} -\cos t & 1 \\ 1 & -\sec t \end{bmatrix} x(t)+ \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -\sin t \end{bmatrix}; \ \ x(0)=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $ has a unique solution of the form $ \ \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=X_h+\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \cos t \end{bmatrix} \ $ ,

where $ \ X_h \ $ is a solution of the homogeneous system $ \ x'(t) =\begin{bmatrix} -\cos t & 1 \\ 1 & -\sec t \end{bmatrix} x(t) \ $

**Answer:**

The given equation is inhomogeneous, thus the solution is of the form

$ X=X_h+X_{PI} \ $ , where $ \ X_{PI} \ $ is for the non-homogeneous part.

But I am unable to explain why the given solution is valid and unique.

Help me out

Comment: Hint: what is the determinant of the matrix multiplying $x(t)$? What are its eigenvectors?

Comment: The eigen values are $ \ \lambda=0 \ , \ \lambda=-(\cos t+\sec t) \ $. Now what to do ?

Comment: To check that $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \cos{t} \end{bmatrix}$ is a solution of the ODE, plug it into the equation.  You know now that any solution of the nonhomogeneous linear ODE is of the form $X_h + \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \cos{t} \end{bmatrix}$.  The existence and uniqueness theorem for linear ODEs guarantees that *some* solution to the IVP exists, and is unique.